# Can't reach the site from another computer

Tags: prestashop

I have installed Prestashop and I can see the site and the back office. But my friend that I'm running the site with can't reach it from his computer. Just getting browser default Page not found. Have tried turn off all cache and IP settings in PS. And clear the browser cache. But nothing works.

What is the problem?

Comment: Try giving him the ip address for the site, followed by the extension. a simple way to get the IP, is to ping subdomain.yourhostname.com. Once you get the ipaddress, try having your friend enter the url, in this format [ipaddress]/extension. See if that works. Then we can possible work the rest of issue out from there.

Comment: I uploaded it on a web hosting provider where I am customer. So it's live and public on www. And have an own domain pointed to it. And everything works without any problem for me on my computer. He just said it worked from his phone. So the problem appears to be just from his computer.

Comment: It seems to be very random. Suddenly my friend could reach the site from his computer at his place. But now when he came to my place it doesn't work. And I can't reach it from my mobile phone. "Server not found".